# Regex to capture string with two rules

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have the following regex that should be capturing 1 group on the first phrase, and three groups on the second phrase.
But for some reason, when I add the optional group with the two right groups, it does not capture string one.

**regex (case insensitive)**

`(^(?<FULLTEXT>.*))\s?(?:(?<AREA>[a-z]{4,4}).(?<SQRM>[\d]+))$`

**phrases**

```
MASTER BEDROOM

LIVING ROOM LVRM 103
```

Phrases will always be:
1 - full text
2 - ends with AREA - which is 4 character string (always) + SQRM 3 digit (always). Anything before that is the fulltext.

Sentence #2 captures: 
FULLTEXT - LIVING ROOM
AREA - LVRM
SQRM - 103

Sentence #1 SHOULD capture FULLTEXT only, but it captures nothing....

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Use `^(?<FULLTEXT>.*?)\s*(?:(?<AREA>[a-z]{4})\s*(?<SQRM>\d+))?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDrdZm/2).

Comment: wow, beautiful @WiktorStribiżew, thanks! I will accept your answer

Comment: What, if anything, is to be matched and captured if the string were `'LIVING 103'`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland the pre-processor will ensure that wont happen, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?<FULLTEXT>.*?)\s*(?:(?<AREA>[a-z]{4})\s*(?<SQRM>\d+))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NDrdZm/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<FULLTEXT>.*?)` - Group "FULLTEXT": any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:(?<AREA>[a-z]{4})\s*(?<SQRM>\d+))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `(?<AREA>[a-z]{4})` - Group "AREA": four letters
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `(?<SQRM>\d+)` - Group "SQRM": 1+ digits
- `$` - end of string.